# 'XHR returned response code 403' message when trying to Pin

Tags: xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-403, pinterest, pins

I have been happily Pinning away on my Pinterest account. I never overdo it and one day i got the following messages after i tried to Pin one of my photos:
**XHR returned response code 403**

it is almost a week and i still get this message when trying to pin photos from my laptop using either Internet Explorer or Firefox. I can Pin from my mobile.
I tried to contact Pinterest and asking a question, i tried to tweet them..I have not received any answer.
I do not use any 'automatic' system to upload my pictures, all is done by me manually when i have time.

Can anyone explain to me what  the message i get means and how to get rid of it and go back to Pin from my laptop, please?
many thanks in advance
Anna

Answer (score 1):

The file size is too large.
I decreased my image size from 11mb to 2.1 mb (still a big image) in Photoshop and the 403 error went away on the subsequent upload.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this message today after loading 1 image. XHR returned response code 403.

Have you used Pinterest Help?  I received this after I submitted my issue.  It was a canned response, but I've had luck in the past:

---

XHR returned response code 403

Jul 22 21:13

Hi IK,

Sorry you're having trouble with Pinterest! Here are some issues we're working on:

https://help.pinterest.com/forums/21191723

If you still need help, send us:

1. A screenshot of what you're seeing (learn how here: http://take-a-screenshot.org)
2. The specific error message you’re seeing, if any
3. Any other details you think would be helpful

We’re still a small team, so unfortunately we can’t write back to all emails, but we read them to find and fix any issues our pinners are having. If your issue gets fixed write back and let us know!

- The Pinterest Team

Answer (score -1):

Try resizing your images.

413 - Request Entity Too Large
The 413 status code indicates that the request was larger than the server is able to handle, either due to physical constraints or to settings. Usually, this occurs when a file is sent using the POST method from a form, and the file is larger than the maximum size allowed in the server settings

Comment: You're talking about a 413 error, and the OP is getting a 403.  As a result your suggestion is irrelevant.  Also, for future reference if you're quoting another source, you need to mark it as a quote and link back to it.  http://andthatsjazz.org/StatCodes.html

Comment: I receive both 403 and 413 errors when attempting to upload a file over 11mb. Which error occurs appears random - they are generated by the same user action, and likely have the same cause.